# Delete Cart Items with Minimum Quantity

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, delete

I have EE 2.7.2 and Store 2.0.4, wondering if anyone else have encountered this issue. I can't delete from cart items with a minimum qty set. However I can delete any other items without a min qty as I mentioned here [Delete from Store Cart](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14510/delete-from-store-cart)

My template looks like:

```
{exp:store:checkout
    form_class="form-horizontal"
    next="shop/customer-details"}

    {items}
        <tr>
            <td>{price}</td>
            <td>
                <input name="items[{key}][item_qty]" value="{item_qty}" class="input-mini item_qty" />              
                <a href="#" class="remove-product">Remove</a> 

            </td>
        </tr>
    {/items}

{/exp:store:checkout}
```

And the script:

```
$('.remove-product').click(function(){
        // click handler
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            $(this).parents('td').find('.item_qty').val('0');
            $(this).parents('tr').animate({ "opacity": "hide" }, "slow");
            $('#update_cart').click();

            return false;
        }
});
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a My Cart page last night and ran into the bug with the Remove From Cart functionality not working. I used jQuery to solve my problem. Here's my basic code.

```
{exp:store:checkout next="checkout/step1"}
    {items}
        <input type="hidden" name="items[{key}][item_qty]" value="{item_qty}" class="remove-{key}">
        <input id="remove-{key}" type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Remove" class="remove-me">
     {/items}
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

AND

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".remove-me").click(function(){
            var target = $(this).attr("id");
            $("." + target).val("0");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Anna your solution doesn't work for products with a minimum quantity and am looking for a solution for that, as mentioned above i have it working if the product doesn't have min qty set

Comment: You find the min qty on the control panel, product details/stock/Min Order Qty

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Store 2.0.4 if you upgrade to Store 2.0.5 this should fix the problem for you.

Comment: I have upgraded to Store 2.0.6 and the issue is still there

Comment: Can you add your template code to the original question?