# Remove single item from cart via checkbox completely empties cart?

Tags: expresso-store

When I select a checkbox for one product to remove it from the cart, it empties all products. Any ideas why? Here is the code I am using from inside the `{items}` tag. Thanks!

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cart_remove_check" name="remove_items[{key}]" value="1" />
```

Here is my full template code...

```
{embed="wrappers/_main"}
{exp:stash:set name="content" no_results_prefix="pfx"}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      {exp:store:cart}{if no_items}{redirect="get-started"}{/if}{/exp:store:cart}
      <h1>Checkout</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  {exp:store:checkout
    return="checkout/complete/ORDER_HASH"
    require="name|address1|address3|postcode"
    payment_method="stripe"
  }
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
      <h3>Credit Card</h3>
      <p>
        <label>Card Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="payment_card_no" value="">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Name on Card</label>
        <input type="text" id="payment_name" value="">
      </p>
      <label>Expires</label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 columns">
          <select id="payment_exp_month">
            <option value=""></option>
            {exp_month_options}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
          <select id="payment_exp_year">
            <option value=""></option>
            {exp_year_options}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>
        <label>Security Code</label>
        <input type="text" id="payment_card_csc" size="4" value="">
      </p>
      <h3>Billing Address</h3>
      <p>
        <label>Name</label>
        {field:billing_name}
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Address</label>
        {field:billing_address1}
        {field:billing_address2}
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>City</label>
        {field:billing_address3}
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>State</label>
        {field:billing_region}
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Zip</label>
        {field:billing_postcode}
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Phone</label>
        {field:billing_phone}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
      <h3>Email Address</h3>
      <p>
        <label for="order_email">Email Address</label>
        {field:order_email}
      </p>
      <h3>Shipping Address</h3>
        <label for="shipping_same_as_billing">
          <input type="hidden" name="shipping_same_as_billing" value="0">
          <input type="checkbox" id="shipping_same_as_billing" name="shipping_same_as_billing" value="1">
          Same as Billing Details
        </label>
      <div id="shipping_details_drawer">
        <p>
          <label>Name</label>
          {field:shipping_name}
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Address</label>
          {field:shipping_address1}
          {field:shipping_address2}
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>City</label>
          {field:shipping_address3}
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>State</label>
          {field:shipping_region}
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Zip</label>
          {field:shipping_postcode}
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Phone</label>
          {field:shipping_phone}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-8 columns">
          <h3>Items</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="small-4 columns">
          <input class="tiny button expand" type="submit" name="empty_cart" value="Empty Cart">
        </div>
      </div>
      <table width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="75%">Product</th>
            <th width="20%">Price</th>
            <th width="5%"><span id="remove_from_cart_label">x</span></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {items}
            {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
              <tr>
                <td>
                  {title}{if item_qty > 1} (x{item_qty}){/if}
                  {modifiers}
                    <br><span style="font-size: 11px;">Rear Wipers {modifier_value}</span>
                  {/modifiers}
                </td>
                <td>{price}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="cart_remove_check" name="remove_items[{key}]" value="1" /></td>
              </tr>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
          {/items}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-9 columns">
          <p style="text-align:right;">
            Subtotal:<br>
            Tax:<br>
            Shipping:<br>
            Total:
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="small-3 columns">
          <p>
            {order_subtotal}<br>
            {order_tax}<br>
            {order_shipping}<br>
            {order_total}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-5 columns">
          <input class="small button expand" type="submit" name="empty_cart" value="Update Cart">
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 large-7 columns">
          <a href="{path='get-started'}" class="small secondary button expand">Continue Shopping</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
          <input id="checkout_submit" class="large success button expand" type="submit" name="submit" value="Place Order">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="payment_token" name="payment[token]" value="" />
  {/exp:store:checkout}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Comment: What version of EE and Store are you using?

Comment: EE 2.5.5 and Store 1.6.3

Comment: Can you also post your full checkout template code

Comment: Just edited my original post with full template code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "Update Cart" button is named `empty_cart`. By calling it that you are telling Store it should empty the cart when you click it.

Try changing this line:

```
<input class="small button expand" type="submit" name="empty_cart" value="Update Cart">
```

To this:

```
<input class="small button expand" type="submit" value="Update Cart">
```

Comment: Great eye spotting that!

Comment: * drops head in shame * lol - thanks for finding that! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this also in the item loop:

```
<input type="hidden" name="items[{key}][item_qty]" value="{item_qty}" />
```

Comment: No dice. All items are removed.

Comment: It's possible some variation of my fix here may work. My issue was on a newer install: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/15418/28